# Getting data type of attributes of Account in Quickbook Online

Tags: python-3.x, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

How can i describe an Quickbook Online object like Account so that i can know what data type each attributes of the Account takes? Using Query or any library that helps to do that. (API Explorer is not a preferable solution for my use case)

Answer (score 0):

The place to get this data is from the `.XSD` files that Intuit produces. The `.XSD`s give you information like:

- what fields each object has
- the lengths of the fields
- which fields are required/optional
- the types of the fields
- etc. etc. etc.

You can get the `.XSD`s here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/learn/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/minor-versions